# Making dynamic change urls based on language asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, dynamic

I'm making a website that needs to be in more then one language. So far I'm thinking of using resource files and have found a tutorial on how to use those. But my question is if its possible to make the URL's change too? So that when you choose English you have /AboutUs and if you choose German you have /ÜberUns instead. I know that I can make a new controller for each language but I would really like it if I could include this in the resource files some way.

Comment: Should be possible to register custom routing with localized names, take a look at custom routes.

This is a blog posthabout exactly this too: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-(ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms).aspx

Comment: I looked over it and it seem to work, but I would like to be able to change the url depending on the CultureInfo instead. So if cultureinfo is fr-FR the home become "Demarrer" and if its en-US it become "Home".
Hope it makes sense

Comment: That seems to be covered in the blog post unless I'm mistaken. Can you elaborate on what you need?

Comment: It might be because I don't understand everything the blog post says, its quite old so some of the points it makes semes outdated. But I would like to to what he does, when the url change so does the cultureinfo, I just dont see anywhere where the cultureinfo is set. Keep in mind that this is the first time I'm trying to work with cultrueinfo and language

Comment: CultureInfo is set on the thread or via config (ie web.config), or can be updated manually in code (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture/CurrentUICulture). At the bottom of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.71).aspx) page is an example of how to set it to user language (providing their browser is set up correctly).